# Ошибка доступа к файлам документации при компиляции

Tags: c#, visual-studio

В общем, иногда при сборке проекта вылетает ошибка `access denied` и указывается путь к XML документации.
В чем может быть проблема? Данный файл ничего не должно держать.

```
error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'BlaBlaBla.xml' -- 'Access to the path 'BlaBlaBla.xml' is denied.'
```

Comment: Было бы проще понять вопрос, если бы вы показали сборочные логи, или хотя-бы значимую их часть.

Comment: @aepot добавил, но там нету ничего интересного

Comment: В документации используются ссылки `cref` на типы в другом проекте?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Имелось в виду полные сборочные логи, а не краткую информацию что по умолчанию выводит студия.